# Blazor Virtualize update when request change

Tags: blazor

I have a component that display many athletes from a database up to 200000.
It work well but when I added a select with a list of countries tou filter result I can see the result count updated but the Virtualize component is not updated until I scroll ?

```razor
@page "/persons"
@inject HttpClient Http


<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <h1>@($"{totalindividu:### ### ##0}") athletes linked</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <select class="form-control" @onchange="ChangePays">
                <option value="-1" selected>Pas de sélection sur le pays</option>
                @if (pays != null)
                {
                    @foreach (var p in pays)
                    {
                    <option value="@p.aatpays_id">@p.aaipays_nom</option>
                    }
                }
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-4"><p>@selpays</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Code</th>
                        <th>Nom long</th>
                        <th>Pays</th>
                        <th>Discipline</th>
                        <th>Date de naissance</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <Virtualize Context="individu" ItemsProvider="@LoadIndividus">
                        <ItemContent>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width: 100px">@individu.aatindividu_id</td>
                                <td style="width: 100px">@individu.aalindividu_code</td>
                                <td>@individu.aaiindividu_nomLong</td>
                                <td style="width: 200px">@individu.aaipays_nom</td>
                                <td style="width: 200px">@individu.aaidiscipline_nom</td>
                                <td style="width: 100px">@individu.aatindividu_dateNaissance</td>
                            </tr>
                        </ItemContent>
                        <Placeholder>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width: 100px">Loading...</td>
                                <td style="width: 100px">Loading...</td>
                                <td>Loading...</td>
                                <td style="width: 200px">Loading...</td>
                                <td style="width: 200px">Loading...</td>
                                <td style="width: 100px">Loading...</td>
                            </tr>
                        </Placeholder>
                    </Virtualize>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    private int totalindividu = 0;
    private string selpays = "-1";
    private BdsPays[] pays = null;
    private BdsIndividu[] individus = null;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        pays = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<BdsPays[]>("api/BdsAa/pays/1");
        //individus = await LoadIndividus(0, 50);
    }

    private async Task<BdsIndividu[]> LoadIndividus(int start, int count)
    {
        totalindividu = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<int>($"api/BdsAa/individusinoutcount/1/33/{selpays}");
        individus = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<BdsIndividu[]>($"api/BdsAa/individusinout/1/33/{start}/{count}/{selpays}");
        return individus;
    }

    private async ValueTask<ItemsProviderResult<BdsIndividu>> LoadIndividus(ItemsProviderRequest request)
    {
        individus = await LoadIndividus(request.StartIndex, request.Count);
        StateHasChanged();
        return new ItemsProviderResult<BdsIndividu>(individus, totalindividu);
    }

    private async Task ChangePays(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        selpays = e.Value.ToString();
        individus = null;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Any idea to force update of table when my filter change ?

Jean

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to call `RefreshDataAsync()` as follows.

From [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/26110#issuecomment-696300394) issue where this functionality was added

> For the more general case where the developer uses ItemsProvider, we should add a new public async Task RefreshDataAsync method on Virtualize. Developers can call this if they have reason to think the underlying data source output may have changed, for example when a user clicks a "Refresh" button. This would just do the same thing that happens when the user scrolls into a new set of data.

Comment: Thanks it's exactly what I want but it is not implemented so far I think ?

Answer (score 5):

To expand a little on Mike's post, you'll need to add a reference to your Virtualize component like this:

```cs
<Virtualize @ref="ArticleContainer" ItemsProvider="LoadArticles">
[...]
</Virtualize>

@code {
    private Virtualize<Article> ArticleContainer { get; set; }
}
```

With the reference, you can then trigger a refresh. Note that this does not cause the component to render again (if it's async!), you will have to call `StateHasChanged()` as well.

```cs
private async Task ReloadArticles()
{
    await ArticleContainer.RefreshDataAsync();
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

Comment: The container is always null for me. Is assigning it using @ref supposed to initialise it or is there another step to take? If I new() it up myself, I get "the render handle was not yet assigned"

Comment: No, `@ref` should initialize it. Maybe you have the wrong type.

Comment: StateHasChanged in my case is not required as the Virtualize calls the ItemsProvider function once it is refreshed

Answer (score 0):

Just label your Virtualize with @ref and perform your OnInput event to refreshdataasync on your ref

```
<div class="form-floating">
 <input class="form-control" value="@FilterInvoice" type="text" 
 placeholder="Filter Invoice..." id="idfilterInvoice"                       
 @oninput="@FilterChangeInvoice">
 <label for="idfilterInvoice">Filter Invoice</label>
 </div>

 <Virtualize @ref="ordersContainer" ItemsProvider="LoadOrders" 
 Context="..." >
 [...]
 </Virtualize>

@code {
    private Virtualize<Order> ordersContainer { get; set; }
    private Order _order = new Order();

    private async Task FilterChangeInvoice(ChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        FilterInvoice = args.Value.ToString();
        await ordersContainer.RefreshDataAsync();
         StateHasChanged();    
    }

        private async ValueTask<ItemsProviderResult<Order>> LoadOrders(ItemsProviderRequest request)
    { ....}
}
```